# Symmetric Positive Definite and Gradient Proof

Tags: optimization, proof-writing, convex-optimization

I have the function $f(x)=\frac {1}{2} \mathbf x^T Q \mathbf x - \mathbf b^T \mathbf x$ where $Q$ is symmetric.

I'm trying to show that solving $\nabla f(\mathbf x) = 0$ is equivalent to solving  $Q \mathbf x = \mathbf b$

I've already proved that if $Q$ is positive definite, then $Q$ is invertible, and then $Q^{-1}$ is also positive definite. Any function that is symmetric positive definite is convex. Therefore $f$ is convex.

A convex function is guaranteed to have a local minimum which is also a global minimum which is why $\nabla f(\mathbf x) = 0$ is true.

How do I show the equivalence in an elegant way though?

Comment: What does the notation $b^{**T**}x$ mean?

Comment: To make the letter bold I read that I'm supposed to put two **'s before and after it... it didn't come out right though! If you know how to fix it- that'd be great! It's supposed to be the vector b transpose and then the vector x.

Comment: Using an orthogonal change of coordinates which diagonalizes $Q$, your equation is just $f(x) = \sum_i \frac{1}{2} \lambda_i x_i^2 - b_i x_i$.  You can calculate the gradient of this function directly.

Comment: In math mode, use `\mathbf{...}` for bold. For more information, see [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/856).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In components, the assert is straightforward:
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij} Q_{ij} x_ix_j - \sum_i b_i x_i.
$$

So (using $Q$'s symmetry):
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i} Q_{ik} x_i + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j} Q_{kj} x_j - b_k = \sum_j Q_{kj} x_j - b_k ,
$$

which are exactly the components of the vector:
$$
\nabla f = Qx - b.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Just compute $\nabla f$ directly. Because $Q$ is symmetric, you get $\nabla f(\mathbf x) = Q\mathbf x - \mathbf b$.